# Django query also return data from ForeignKey Table

Tags: python, django

I am facing issue on how to retrieve data of foreign key table.

My 2 models looks like these..

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    orderId = models.IntegerField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customers,blank=True,null=True)

class Customers(models.Model):
    Domain= models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True ,blank=True)
    CustomerName= models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
```

I want to list out all `orders` from `Orders` model and also `CustomerName` from `Customers` model through reference of `customer_id` to `Customers` Model

What should I write in my below views.py

```
class OrderList(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    def get(self,request):
             orders=Orders.objects.all()
             serializer = OrderSerializer(orders,many=True)
             return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: You have to explain more what you want if you wanna better answers.

Comment: I edited somewhat my question , which part you are not able to get?

Comment: "through reference of customer_id to Customers Model"

Comment: Customer.objects.values('id', "CustomerName") something like this?
This will give you all the Customer's Name and id in dictionaries for example:

[{"id"1: "CustomerName":"HI"},{"id"1: "CustomerName":"HELLO"}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference attributes of foreign key directly. In your case you can use

```
order.customer.CustomerName
```

to reference `CustomerName` for given order.